# R Calculating overnight time difference (when start time is PM and end time is AM of the next day)

Tags: r, datetime

I need the difference in hours between a shift start and end time. The start and end times are character strings in a 12 hour am/pm format. We can assume the start times are all on the same calandar day, but end times can go to the following day (overnight shifts). `difftime` treats them as on the same date, resulting in differences that calculate in the wrong direction: if start time is 7:00 PM and end time is 4:00 AM, a 9 hour shift is calculated as 15 hours. Is it possible to calculate these time differences without creating a more complicated function?

```
df= structure(c("7:00 AM", "7:00 PM", "8:00 AM", "10:00 PM", 
            "4:00 PM", "4:00 AM", "5:00 PM", "6:00 AM"), .Dim = c(4L, 2L))

as.numeric(difftime(
   strptime(df[,2], "%I:%M %p" ),
   strptime(df[,1], "%I:%M %p" ),
   units='hours'))
[1]   9 -15   9 -16
```

The results I'm looking for should be:

```
[1] 9 9 9 8
```

Comment: I guess you could just save the result somewhere and then add `24` to the negative values, something like `temp <- as.numeric(difftime(
  strptime(df[,2], "%I:%M %p" ),
  strptime(df[,1], "%I:%M %p" ),
  units='hours')) ; temp[temp < 0] <- temp[temp < 0] + 24`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it.

```
shift.dur <- function(m){
    hours<- as.numeric(difftime(
        strptime(df[,2], "%I:%M %p" ),
        strptime(df[,1], "%I:%M %p" ),
        units='hours'))
    hours[hours<0] <- 24+hours[hours<0] 
    hours
}
```